# Unable to send an email by python

Tags: python-3.x, email

Im trying to send a basic email by this script

```
s = smtplib.SMTP(email_user, 587)
s.starttls()
s.login(email_user, pasword)
message = 'Hi There, sending this email from python'
s.sendmail(email_user, email_user, message)
s.quit()
```

and getting the following error

```
for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: -1 which email service are you using? Is this the complete code, The full traceback is not present, you've mixed code with the error itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your first line:

```
s = smtplib.SMTP(email_user, 587)
```

'email_user' should instead be the email server, example 'smtp.gmail.com'